# What is the best regex for including the entire first number after a square root?

Tags: java, regex

Sorry for the butchered title. I am attempting to create a calculator and need to find the first number (including negative and decimals) in a number of different cases.

One particularly difficult case includes square roots. Currently, it doesn't include anything past the first number. It is supposed to include the *entire* number.

Pattern for first number:
`"[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?(?=.*(\\-)?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?)"`

Ex.`"√10"` returns `1` instead of `10`.

Any help is appreicated! Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: Why are you mixing `[0-9]` and `\\d`? They mean the same thing, so mixing them is confusing, since we then start wonder why, when there is no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note sure if you are trying to find the number specifically following the square root. If so, this (Java) pattern could work:

`"(?<=√)([-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)"`

- `(?<=√)`: non-capturing look behind: the rest will match only if it is preceded by the square-root sign. Remove this part if you don't care about the square-root dependency
- `[-+]?`: A minus sign, a plus sign, or nothing
- `\\d+`: 1 or more digits
- `(\\.\\d+)?`: optionally, a dot followed by one or more digits

Here's a quick example of how it works:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternTest {

    static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=√)([-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)");

    static void testPattern(String input) {
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("input: " + input + ", found: " + matcher.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("input: " + input + ", not found");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testPattern("1234");
        testPattern("√1234");
        testPattern("√-1234.0");
        testPattern("√+1234.04");
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
input: 1234, not found
input: √1234, found: 1234
input: √-1234.0, found: -1234.0
input: √+1234.04, found: +1234.04
```

Comment: This answer was better than the other option. I ended up using a pattern just like this! Hopefully this can help others. Thanks :)